# Jface tableviewer - Columns are not spaced out even with tablecolumnlayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using a jface tableviewer with a tablecolumnlayout (for it's parent composite) in my eclipse RCP application.

I see that, in my view, the columns are equally spaced out to cover the entire width of the table.. So far so good.

We have a functionality where we need to save & load the table layout . Basically user can hide/ re-order any number of columns and he wishes to save that particular layout..

I am using the eclipse preferences API to save/retrieve the table layout.

The view opens with a default layout (with all columns & with the default ordering ) when the view is opened for the 1st time. Hence, I would save a DEFAULT layout(with the default ordering & column widths) whenever the view loads so that user can come back to the original layout at any time.

**But, the problem here is when I try to load the default layout, I see that the columns are NOT equally spaced out and there is an empty column at the end.**

What can i possibly do to achieve the default behaviour where columns get equally spaced out to cover the width of the table?

Note: I tried invoking the layout() of table's parent composite or calling the redraw of both table as well as composite but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above mentioned issue.

SWT increases the given width of the columns during view rendering so that the entire table width is occupied.

I was able to get the increased width of each column only when the view was about to be rendered (during part Activation ).

If I asked for the column width just after using the tablecolumnlayout, I was still getting the predefined width.

As a solution to this, I moved my code to save the default layout during part activation so that the actual increased width is obtained.